# How to use model from huggingface to make an "app" which can transcribe a local indian language?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, openai-whisper

I'm looking to use this finetuned(https://huggingface.co/thennal/whisper-medium-ml) whisper model to make an app for personal use. I want to use google colaboratory to run this.

I'm not a developer and have no idea how to go about with this, but I need this app right now. Any of your valuable help is much appreciated.

I tried multiple tutorials, but I don't know how to use this model within colaboratory. I don't even know how to google this particular problem.

I just want this hugging face model to run within my google colaboratory and transcribe the audio into a text format.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To use a huggingface model, in this case [whisper-medium-ml](https://huggingface.co/thennal/whisper-medium-ml), we can use simple but efficient way with `high-level pipeline function` provided by huggingface. It is designed to abstract most of the complex code from the library, offering a simple API dedicated to several tasks including your `automatic speech recognition (asr)` task as well. Here is the code to do it within google colab

```
# import high-level pipeline 
from transformers import pipeline

# This line will load your desired model
pipe = pipeline("automatic-speech-recognition", model="thennal/whisper-medium-ml")
```

This code above will load the model from huggingface model hub in order to be called to transcribe your audio file. Then, to get a transcribed output in text format, here is the last action that must be done.

```
# to get an output, the file can be mp4, wav, or others
print(pipe("path_to_voicefile.mp4")) # will get a transcribed output as a text
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Appreciate you taking time to answer. The code you wrote is working perfectly but I'm encountering one issue- **its not transcribing the entire file, rather, a small segment of it perhaps a few seconds**.
The comment said to use max_new_token to increase the size of text. I tried that but was unable to get exact syntax to write that.
Here's the code that I entered.

```
 print(pipe("/content/untitled2.mp3",), (max_new_tokens(int, 500)))
```

Comment: the max_new_tokens is a parameter of pipeline function, so, you need to pass number of max_new_tokens directly into pipe like this `print(pipe("/content/untitled2.mp3", max_new_tokens=500))`

Comment: thanks for staying with me on this, I ran the code but it is outputing this error:
```
in greedy_search(self,...,, **model_kwargs)
   2370                 continue  # don't waste resources running the code we don't need
  
-> 2372             next_token_logits = outputs.logits[:, -1, :]
   2373 
   2374             # pre-process distribution

IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 0
```

Comment: When I reduce the size max new token to 300, it works but it still doesn't transcribe the entire audio file(3min long), in face, it transcribes much lesser**(around 5 seconds)** than earlier**(around 10 seconds)**.
Is there a way to transcribe the entire file, preferably in one go.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, in case that you have a very long audio file, we can chunking the initial audio file into shorter samples (e.g. 10 seconds for each chunk) before we let the model transcribe it. This can be done by passing one more parameters that is: `print(pipe("/content/untitled2.mp3", max_new_tokens=100, chunk_length_s=10))` . The explanation of how chunking work can be read at https://huggingface.co/blog/asr-chunking